# Получить код из файла формата .php

Tags: php, файлы, переменные

### Файлы

Имеем файл **TestPage.php**,в котором находится любой код php. Выглядит он так:

```
<?php
    echo(5+5);
?>
```

Ещё имеем файл **Interp.php**, в котором написан сам основной скрипт.

> Нужно получить php код из файла **TestPage.php**, в любую переменную. Но код должен быть без тега php, то есть без `<?php` и `?>`. Но как это сделать?

### Вот что пока есть

Получаем текст из файла **TestPage.php**, и записываем в переменную **$file**.

```
$file = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('TestPage.php'));
```

Получается так, что в переменной **$file** находится строка `<?php echo(5+5); ?>`
И я пытаюсь убрать тег php, но если я убраю его через **str_replace()** или **preg_match()** - то это не работает.

### Например **str_replace()**

Скрипт `echo(str_replace('','<?php',$file));` по идеи должен удалить `<?php`,но он так не считает и выводит мне это `<?php echo(5+5); ?>`, если заюзать `htmlspecialchars()`, вот так `echo(str_replace('',htmlspecialchars('<?php'),$file));` выводит всё-равно туже самую строку.

Comment: А правильный порядок аргументов `str_replace` кто будет соблюдать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений - это вырезать ограничители регулярным выражением

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('TestPage.php');
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('/<\?php|\?>/', '', $file));
```

Однако, и `str_replace()` тоже даст результат, если вы вызовете его до применения функции `htmlspecialchars()`

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('TestPage.php');
$file = str_replace(array('<?php', '?>'), '', $file);
echo htmlspecialchars($file);
```

Обратите внимание в `str_replace()` первым аргументом идет искомое значение, а вторым - то, чем замещаем. В примере выше для сокращения в качестве первого аргумента был задействован массив искомых значений.